# from subprocess import check_output - what does it mean

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

`from subprocess import check_output`
I'm unable to understand the purpose of this line in jupyter notebook. Can someone please explain me why do we need this library in simple words.
What I am trying to understand is what would check_output do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Nobody can explain why your particular notebook *needs* this function without seeing it. What is it about the function itself you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what is being done in the jupyter notebook, it is rather hard to say.

That being said, it is simply importing the check_output class from the subprocess module.

I am not intimate enough with this library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this library, but from the research I did, it is for collecting the response to commands run on the console.

Example:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"], shell=True)
print(result)

b'"Hello World!"\r\n'
```

```py
from subprocess import check_output
result = check_output(["python", "--version"], shell=True)
print(result)

b'Python 3.9.6\r\n'
```

Comment: hey thanks for answer. but can you tell me what would result = check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"]) this line return in your code?

Comment: I am not familiar with this library, but from the research I did, it is for collecting the response to commands run on the console